# Migration from swift 3 to swift 4 - Cannot convert String to expected String.Element

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I am converting my code from swift 3 to swift 4 and getting this error in the following code. I am getting this even when I try to use flatmap to flatten an array

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
>   'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

```
if favoritedProducts.contains("helloWorld") {}
```

The below line of code does not return a [String] instead it is a '[String.Element]' How do I convert it to a [String]. If I try to cast it as a [String], it says it will always fail.

```
let productIDs = allItems.flatMap{$0.productID}
```

Comment: i had same question, +1 for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an `Item` type with a **non optional** `productID` property of type `String` like this

```
struct Item {
    let productID: String
}
```

And you have an array of `Item`

```
let allItems: [Item] = ...
```

Then you can get an array of `productID(s)` using the `map` method

```
let productIDs = allItems.map { $0.productID }
```

Now `productIDs` is `[String]`.

Comment: Awesome. The issue was I was using flatmap when I just needed to use map. In swift 3 that mistake was ok but in swift 4 it didn't work because strings are now arrays of characters I believe.

Comment: Hi, please help me. I have an array of String.Elements and when i'm goint to extract the values into a string, shows error, 'Cannot assign value of type '[String.Element]' (aka 'Array<Character>') to type 'String'.