# Swift Error Cannot convert value of type '[String.Element]' (aka 'Array<Character>') to expected argument type '[String]'

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create an array of letters from a given word by using the following Swift code (I have an array of words for allWords, but for simplicity I've just added an example word there for now):

```
let allWords = ["Leopards"]
var arrayOfLetters = Array(allWords[0])

let everyPossibleArrangementOfLetters = permute(list: arrayOfLetters)

func permute(list: [String], minStringLen: Int = 3) -> Set<String> {
    func permute(fromList: [String], toList: [String], minStringLen: Int, set: inout Set<String>) {
        if toList.count >= minStringLen {
            set.insert(toList.joined(separator: ""))
        }
        if !fromList.isEmpty {
            for (index, item) in fromList.enumerated() {
                var newFrom = fromList
                newFrom.remove(at: index)
                permute(fromList: newFrom, toList: toList + [item], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
            }
        }
    }

    var set = Set<String>()
    permute(fromList: list, toList:[], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
    return set
}
```

I obtained this code from: [Calculate all permutations of a string in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968470/calculate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But the following error is presented:
Cannot convert value of type '[String.Element]' (aka 'Array') to expected argument type '[String]'

I attempted the following, which works, but it takes over 10 seconds per word (depending on number of repeat letters) and I was hoping to find a better solution.

```
var arrayOfLetters: [String] = []

     for letter in allWords[0] {
     arrayOfLetters.append(String(letter))
     }

     let everyPossibleArrangementOfLetters = permute(list: arrayOfLetters)
```

I wasn't able to get the following solution to work, although I think is has promise I couldn't get past the productID name of items in the array whereas my array items aren't named...
[Migration from swift 3 to swift 4 - Cannot convert String to expected String.Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383874/migration-from-swift-3-to-swift-4-cannot-convert-string-to-expected-string-ele?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I'm also creating another array and checking each of those words to ensure their validity, and I run into the same error which I correct in the same way with array.append which is adding a lot more time in that location as well.

```
var everyPossibleArrangementOfLettersPartDeux: [String] = []
     for word in everyPossibleArrangementOfLetters {
     everyPossibleArrangementOfLettersPartDeux.append(word)
     }

numberOfRealWords = possibleAnagrams(wordArray: everyPossibleArrangementOfLettersPartDeux)

func possibleAnagrams(wordArray: [String]) -> Int {

    func isReal(word: String) -> Bool {
        let checker = UITextChecker()
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.utf16.count)
        let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")

        return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
    }

    var count = 0

    for word in wordArray {
        if isReal(word: word) {
            count += 1
            //print(word)
        }

        }
        return count
        }
```

I'm hoping the same replacement for array.append will work in both spots.

Comment: For troubleshooting this error, note that if you try to pass `[myArray]` where you intended to pass `myArray`, this is the error that you'll get. Fix that typo & you're in business!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `Array(allWords[0])` produces `[Character]` and not the `[String]` that you need.

You can call `map` on a `String` (which is a collection of `Character`s and use `String.init` on each character to convert it to a `String`).  The result of the `map` will be `[String]`:

```
var arrayOfLetters = allWords[0].map(String.init)
```

---

Notes:

1. When I tried this in a Playground, I was getting the mysterious message `Fatal error: Only BidirectionalCollections can be advanced by a negative amount`.  This seems to be a Playground issue, because it works correctly in an app.
2. Just the word `"Leopards"` produces `109,536` permutations.

---

**Another Approach**

Another approach to the problem is to realize that `permute` doesn't have to work on `[String]`.  It could use `[Character]` instead.  Also, since you are always starting with a `String`, why not pass that string to the outer `permute` and let it create the `[Character]` for you.

Finally, since it is logical to think that you might just want anagrams of the original word, make `minStringLen` an optional with a value of `nil` and just use `word.count` if the value is not specified.

```
func permute(word: String, minStringLen: Int? = nil) -> Set<String> {
    func permute(fromList: [Character], toList: [Character], minStringLen: Int, set: inout Set<String>) {
        if toList.count >= minStringLen {
            set.insert(String(toList))
        }
        if !fromList.isEmpty {
            for (index, item) in fromList.enumerated() {
                var newFrom = fromList
                newFrom.remove(at: index)
                permute(fromList: newFrom, toList: toList + [item], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
            }
        }
    }

    var set = Set<String>()
    permute(fromList: Array(word), toList:[], minStringLen: minStringLen ?? word.count, set: &set)
    return set
}
```

Examples:

```
print(permute(word: "foo", minStringLen: 1))
```

> ```
> ["of", "foo", "f", "fo", "o", "oof", "oo", "ofo"]
> ```

```
print(permute(word: "foo"))
```

> ```
> ["foo", "oof", "ofo"]
> ```

Comment: This is the most intelligent way to do it, although I confess that I find it forgettable because I've never really understood the logic of writing the expression in this way. This is very much a side point but my view is that `[String]("Leopard")` or `[String]("Leopard".characters)` would make more sense and be more consistent with `[Int](1...3)` etc. but I'd be delighted if someone could help me see the light on this.

Comment: A `String` is once again a collection of `Character`, so calling `map` on a `String` operates on each `Character`.  Calling `String.init` with each `Character` converts it into a `String`.

Comment: The problem is type conversion.  `[String]("Leopard")` doesn't work because this is no initializer for `Array<String>` that takes a `String` or an `Array<Character>`.  Each `Character` needs to be converted to a `String` which can't be done with casting.  You must call a `String` initializer on every `Character`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Comment: I've addressed the mysterious error in a separate question. See [Fatal error: Only BidirectionalCollections can be advanced by a negative amount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52128359/1033581)

Answer (score 4):

This line is returning a `Character` array, not a `String` one:

```
var arrayOfLetters = Array(allWords[0])
```

You can convert this to a `String` array like so:

```
var arrayOfLetters = Array(allWords[0]).map{String($0)}
```

You could alternatively write:

```
var arrayOfLetters = allWords[0].characters.map{String($0)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If, it is optional character or string

```
usedLetters.append(currentWord.randomElement().map(String.init)!)
```

Here usedLetters is Array[String]
currentWord is Optional string