# Fatal error: Only BidirectionalCollections can be advanced by a negative amount

Tags: swift, set, swift-playground, xcode9.4

How to convert an Array to a Set using Xcode Playground? We tried:

```
let a = Array(0 ..< 1000)
let s = Set(a)
```

This produces at run time:

> Fatal error: Only BidirectionalCollections can be advanced by a negative amount

Issue happening with both Xcode 9.4 Playground and Xcode 10 beta 3 Playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Xcode 10 beta 6 and newer, so I've updated the workaround to only apply for older swift versions.

---

For older Xcode versions (like Xcode 9.4), this may be caused by the number of elements being greater than 100.

Workaround [found by Karoy Lorentey](https://forums.swift.org/t/fatal-error-only-bidirectionalcollections-can-be-advanced-by-a-negative-amount/13779)
, is to customize Set's playground description:

```
#if !swift(>=4.2)
extension Set: CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible {
    public var playgroundDescription: Any {
        return description
    }
}
#endif

let a = Array(0 ..< 1000)
let s = Set(a)
```

Doing like that will not have error at run time.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in Xcode 10b6. It's possible this was a bug that's been fixed?